# Web API PUT Return Object with Proper HTTP Status Code

Tags: c#, .net-core

First, I want to say `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpGet("{id}")]`, and `[HttpPost]` is working correctly. However I'm running into a challenge with `[HttpPut]`, and almost everywhere I look, the solution is to return without a status code.

I'm using visual studio 2019 with a project type of "ASP.NET Core Web Application" and "API" (ASP.NET Core 3.1).

I'm also using a secondary project in the same visual studio solution with the type(C#) "Class Library (.NET Standard)".

I'm using Postman to test the http request calls.

The following (Additional) NuGet Packages are required to be installed:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
- System.ComponentModel.Annotations

The Solution Explorer:

[image]

There is a lot of code to cover with the .net core, and I will show it all here (as far as what has **changed**).

**The Project "CoreStudy.Api" Code:**

Startup.cs

```
using CoreStudy.Data.Context;
using CoreStudy.Data.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace CoreStudy.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddScoped<PeopleRepository>(); // add this line
            services.AddDbContext<PersonContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("PeopleInventory")); // add this line, requires NuGet package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory"
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

PeopleController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using CoreStudy.Data.Repository;
using CoreStudy.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace CoreStudy.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("people")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly PeopleRepository _repository;

        public PeopleController(PeopleRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<PersonModel>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public IActionResult GetPeople()
        {
            return Ok(_repository.GetPeople());
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(PersonModel), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public IActionResult GetPersonById(int id)
        {
            var person = _repository.GetPersonById(id);
            if (person == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(person);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddPersonAsync([FromBody] PersonModel person)
        {
            if((_repository.GetPersonById(person.id) != null) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.name))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            int peopleAdded = await _repository.AddPersonAsync(person);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetPersonById), new { person.id }, person);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(PersonModel), StatusCodes.Status202Accepted)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePersonNameByIdAsync([FromBody] PersonModel person)
        {
            if (_repository.GetPersonById(person.id) == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.name))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            PersonModel updatedPerson = await _repository.ChangePersonNameAsync(person);
            return Ok(updatedPerson);
        }
    }
}
```

**The Project "CoreStudy.Data" Code:**

PersonContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CoreStudy.Data.Models;

namespace CoreStudy.Data.Context
{
    public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {
        public PersonContext(DbContextOptions<PersonContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<PersonModel> people { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PersonModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CoreStudy.Data.Models
{
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string name { get; set; }

        public string position { get; set; }

        public PersonModel() { }
        public PersonModel(string name, string position)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.position = position;
        }
        public PersonModel(int id, string name, string position)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.position = position;
        }
    }
}
```

PeopleRepository.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CoreStudy.Data.Models;
using CoreStudy.Data.Context;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreStudy.Data.Repository
{
    public class PeopleRepository
    {
        private readonly PersonContext context;

        public PeopleRepository(PersonContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;

            if (context.people.Count() == 0)
            {
                context.people.AddRange(
                    new PersonModel
                    {
                        name = "shaggy",
                        position = "screwball"
                    },
                    new PersonModel
                    {
                        name = "scooby",
                        position = "screwball dog"
                    },
                    new PersonModel
                    {
                        name = "fred",
                        position = "leader"
                    },
                    new PersonModel
                    {
                        name = "velma",
                        position = "smart one"
                    },
                    new PersonModel
                    {
                        name = "daphne",
                        position = "popular one"
                    });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public List<PersonModel> GetPeople()
        {
            return context.people.ToList();
        }

        public PersonModel GetPersonById(int id)
        {
            PersonModel person = context.people.Find(id); // null if not found
            return person;
        }

        public async Task<int> AddPersonAsync(PersonModel person)
        {
            int rowsAffected = 0;
            context.people.Add(person);
            rowsAffected = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return rowsAffected;
        }

        public async Task<PersonModel> ChangePersonNameAsync(PersonModel person)
        {
            context.people.Update(person);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return GetPersonById(person.id);
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to make a PUT request with postman, I get the following error:

[image]

**The problem is either in one of these two snippets:**

```
public async Task<PersonModel> ChangePersonNameAsync(PersonModel person)
{
    context.people.Update(person); // I thought Update() would be best used here, but not sure
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return GetPersonById(person.id);
}
```

---

```
[HttpPut]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PersonModel), StatusCodes.Status202Accepted)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePersonNameByIdAsync([FromBody] PersonModel person)
{
    if (_repository.GetPersonById(person.id) == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.name))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    PersonModel updatedPerson = await _repository.ChangePersonNameAsync(person);
    return Ok(updatedPerson); // not sure if I should be using Ok() for a PUT
}
```

---

If anyone could help me resolve this, myself (and I'm sure much of the internet) would thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already gets the entity:

```cs
if (_repository.GetPersonById(person.id) == null) { ... }
```

So you need to take that result:

```cs
var personDB = _repository.GetPersonById(person.id);
```

Then check if the variable is `null`

```cs
if(personDB != null) { ... }
```

Then you will need to change the `personDB` properties values with the person (from the PUT parameter) values.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Note: I also had to change `[HttpPut]` to `[HttpPut("{id}")]`

Answer (score 1):

After the line

```
if (_repository.GetPersonById(person.id) == null)
```

The person entity is already being tracked by the DbContext.

You don't need the extra repository layer at all.  Your `PersonContext` already is a perfectly good repository.   Just run:

```
context.people.Update(person); 
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
return Ok(person);
```

in your controller.

Comment: The problem here is context is defined in the repository, not the controller.

Comment: I think you and ljcordero had the same root cause. Looks like the solution is to just store that call in memory, and recall it... `PersonModel personToUpdate = _repository.GetPersonById(person.id);`, then `personToUpdate.name = person.name;`, then `await _repository.ChangePersonNameAsync(personToUpdate);`

Comment: "The problem here is context is defined in the repository, not the controller"  Yes that is a problem.  You introduced an unnecessary layer in your application.  At least put an Update(PersonModel) method, and a SaveChanges() method on your PersonRepository.

Comment: I appreciate the insight on this. I was searching through over 20 different types of videos, documentation, articles, blogs, ect... and am trying to stick with a pattern to what I was using with nodejs/express. So far, this pattern seems to be easy to work with and read for me. Thanks for the input.